# Transform an android application to app widget

Tags: android, widget

I have developped  a weather application but now I want to create an app widget. 
Can I "transform" my application to an app widget?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The short answer: Yes you can. The way how to do this requires that you know how to make an app widget. A bit more general knowledge might be helpful there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you have to implement a widget in the app.

[see this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to use geolocalisation in a widget ?

Comment: it should be the same as you do in the app